# How to randomize an integer variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

How can I randomize a variable in JavaScript between 0-4, so that every time the page loads the variable is different but between 0 and 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/random) for this. To get a (whole) number between 0 and 4 inclusive, use the following:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply's! Worked a charm!

Answer (score 3):

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max  
function getRandomInt(min, max)  
{  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
}
```

from **[mdc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math/random) *(mozilla developer center)***

Comment: You missed the link in my answer? :)

Comment: but fell in love with the typography, so can't delete now. But hey, people vote to BalusC :)